# Filtering text that ends with certain char(all occurrences) in python through regexp

Tags: python, regex, text, filtering

I'm trying to filter text in python

```
import re
text = "Fast charging 25W, USB Power Delivery 3.0, Fast Qi/PMA wireless charging 12W, Reverse wireless charging 4.5W"
regex = re.compile("\w+\s\w+harg\w+\s\d+W")  
mc = regex.findall(text)
print(mc)
```

The result is

> ['Fast charging 25W', 'wireless charging 12W']

However, what I wanna do is get all occurrences end with *W"

> ['Fast charging 125W', 'Fast Qi/PMA wireless charging 12W', 'Reverse wireless charging 4.5W']

The number can be much larger(Like Charge 1250W)
I googled almost 2 hours with lots of document about regexp but in vain. any help will be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: You can still upvote answers, independent from accepting, to honor the effort. :)

Comment: that's good to know, thanks!

Comment: @Josh Kim: Hi Josh, you can still upvote answers ;-), see mine underneath!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for a word boundary, and, if I understand correctly, everything between commas:

```
[^,]+?W\b
```

- Everything that is not a comma, lazy
- Literal uppercase `W`, followed by a word boundary `\b`

[Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nUY4lx/1),
Code Sample:

```
import re
regex = r"[^,]+?W\b"
test_str = ("text = \"Fast charging 25W, USB Power Delivery 3.0, Fast Qi/PMA wireless charging 12W, Reverse wireless charging 4.5W\"\n")
matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE)
for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches, start=1):  
    print ("Match {matchNum} was found at {start}-{end}: {match}".format(matchNum = matchNum, start = match.start(), end = match.end(), match = match.group()))
```

Comment: Here is a code sample using `finditer` to retrieve individual results: https://ideone.com/VZVwzT

Comment: I think you don't have to make it non greedy as the W is before the comma like `[^,]+W\b` +1

Answer (score 2):

You can start the match with a word character, match charging between chars which are not a comma, and then match at least a digit before the W

```
(?<!\S)[^,]*\bcharg\w+\b[^,]*\dW\b
```

**Explanation**

- `(?<!\S)` Assert whitespace boundary on the left
- `[^,]*` Match 0+ occurrences of any char except `,`
- `\bcharg\w+\b` A word boundary, match `charg` followed by 1+ word chars and a word boundary
- `[^,]*` Match 0+ occurrences of any char except `,`
- `\dW\b` Match at least a single digit followed by `W` and a word boundary

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/urrXFV/1)

```
import re

s = "Fast charging 25W, USB Power Delivery 3.0, Fast Qi/PMA wireless charging 12W, Reverse wireless charging 4.5W, Charge 1250W"
print(re.findall(r"(?<!\S)[^,]*\bcharg\w+\b[^,]*\dW\b", s, re.IGNORECASE))
```

Output

```
[
    'Fast charging 25W',
    'Fast Qi/PMA wireless charging 12W',
    'Reverse wireless charging 4.5W',
    'Charge 1250W'
]
```

---

Or if there can only be digits in the part with the `W`, you can exclude matching the digits as well `[^,\d]` and optionally match a decimal part `(?:\.\d+)?`

```
(?<!\S)[^,]*\bcharg\w+\b[^,\d]*\d+(?:\.\d+)?W\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ti1b09/1)

Comment: Thank you for your kind explanation. It's such a pity that I have to choose only one answer.

Answer (score 1):

This will capture all W with one or more digits in front of it

Code:

```
import re
text = "Fast charging 25W, USB Power Delivery 3.0, Fast Qi/PMA wireless charging 12W, Reverse wireless charging 4.5W"

pattern = '((\d[.])?\d+[W])'
matches = [match.group() for match in re.finditer(pattern, text)]
print(matches)
```

Output:

```
['25W', '12W', '4.5W']
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution using numpy using `char.endswith`.

```
import numpy as np

text = "Fast charging 25W, USB Power Delivery 3.0, Fast Qi/PMA wireless charging 12W, Reverse wireless charging 4.5W"
A = np.array(text.split(",")) 
v = np.char.endswith(A, 'W') 
A[v]
```

Output:

```
array(['Fast charging 25W', ' Fast Qi/PMA wireless charging 12W',
   ' Reverse wireless charging 4.5W'], dtype='<U34')
```